# Evitar que salga el mismo texto en dos EditTexts

Tags: java, android, edittext

Utilizo dos EditText (`et_miembro_id`) y (`et_fecha_id`), pero lo que escribo en el `et_miembro_id` es lo que también se agrega en el `et_fecha_id`.

Lo que no quiero es que salga el mismo texto en ambas, quiero que vayan por separado, es decir

- `et_miembro_id` para nombres.
- `et_fecha_id` para escribir una fecha,

pero lo que escribo en miembro se añade sólo en fecha.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

AgregarPersona.java

```
    public class AgregarPersona extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText et;
    EditText et2;
    Button btnAgregar, read_bt;
    SQLControlador dbconeccion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.agregar_persona);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_nombre_id);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_fecha_id);
        btnAgregar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAgregarId);

        dbconeccion = new SQLControlador(this);
        dbconeccion.abrirBaseDeDatos();
        btnAgregar.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnAgregarId:
                String name = et.getText().toString();
                dbconeccion.insertarDatos(name);
                Intent main = new Intent(AgregarPersona.this, MyActivity.class)
                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(main);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

SQLControlador.java

```
public class SQLControlador {

    private DBhelper dbhelper;
    private Context ourcontext;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public SQLControlador(Context c) {
        ourcontext = c;
    }

    public SQLControlador abrirBaseDeDatos() throws SQLException {
        dbhelper = new DBhelper(ourcontext);
        database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void cerrar() {
        dbhelper.close();
    }

    public void insertarDatos(String name) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBhelper.PERSONA_NOMBRE, name);
        cv.put(DBhelper.PERSONA_FECHA, name);
        database.insert(DBhelper.TABLE_MEMBER, null, cv);
    }

    public Cursor leerDatos() {
        String[] todasLasColumnas = new String[] {
                DBhelper.PERSONA_ID,
                DBhelper.PERSONA_NOMBRE,
                DBhelper.PERSONA_FECHA
        };
        Cursor c = database.query(DBhelper.TABLE_MEMBER, todasLasColumnas, null,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

    public int actualizarDatos(long memberID, String memberName, String memberFecha) {
        ContentValues cvActualizar = new ContentValues();
        cvActualizar.put(DBhelper.PERSONA_NOMBRE, memberName);
        cvActualizar.put(DBhelper.PERSONA_FECHA, memberFecha);
        int i = database.update(DBhelper.TABLE_MEMBER, cvActualizar,
                DBhelper.PERSONA_ID + " = " + memberID, null);
        return i;
    }

    public void deleteData(long memberID) {
        database.delete(DBhelper.TABLE_MEMBER, DBhelper.PERSONA_ID + "="
                + memberID, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: y cual es el error?? Podrías aclarar y agregar a tu pregunta. Gracias

Comment: ¿...Y el problema .-.?

Comment: Que no quiero que salga el mismo texto en ambas, quiero que vayan por separado, es decir et_miembro_id = para nombres. et_fecha_id, para escribir una fecha, pero lo que escribo en miembro se añade solo en fecha @josego espero haberme explicado bien

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta lo que acabas de explicar.

Comment: Listo, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar, gracias @josego

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando actualizas los datos, estas escribiendo el Nombre en ambos campos.

En la función:

```
public int actualizarDatos(long memberID, String memberName) {
        ContentValues cvActualizar = new ContentValues();
        cvActualizar.put(DBhelper.MIEMBRO_NOMBRE, memberName);
        cvActualizar.put(DBhelper.MIEMBRO_FECHA, memberName);
        int i = database.update(DBhelper.TABLE_MEMBER, cvActualizar,
                DBhelper.MIEMBRO_ID + " = " + memberID, null);
        return i;
    }
```

Estas escribiendo:

```
        cvActualizar.put(DBhelper.MIEMBRO_NOMBRE, memberName);
        cvActualizar.put(DBhelper.MIEMBRO_FECHA, memberName);
```

En ambos casos, asignas `memberName` tanto al nombre como a la fecha.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Me podrías poner un ejemplo de como añadir otro member?

Comment: Debes modificar los parámetros de la función actualizarDatos a algo como: 'public int actualizarDatos(long memberID, String memberName, String memberFecha)' y sustituir memberName por memberFecha en `cvActualizar.put(DBhelper.MIEMBRO_FECHA, memberName);`. Después te tocará cambiar todas las invocaciones a la función actualizarDatos.

Comment: He añadido lo que me has comentado pero sigue el mismo problema @DavidIsla , he actualizado el código en el primer comentario con los nuevos cambios.

Comment: Sigues teniendo un `dbcon.actualizarDatos(member_id, memName_upd);` en tu ModificarMiembro.java. Ten en cuenta también que todos registros que has guardado con anterioridad se encuentran con la fecha y el nombre iguales.

Comment: Solucionado! Te lo marco como respuesta correcta, tuve que modificar también                 dbconeccion.insertarDatos(name); añadiendole fecha y añadir un nuevo  cv.put con fecha. Gracias por tu ayuda!